# Where i can find Scheduled Jobs in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Need to know following points:

1. Where to locate Scheduled jobs in Oracle SQL Developer?
2. How to remove default date format from SQL Developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jobs can be found within the "Scheduler" node through the "Connections" tab (note: the "Scheduler" node is not provided within the "Schema Browser" tab):
[image: Jobs can be found within the "Scheduler" node through the "Connections" tab]

Alternatively, query

```
select * from user_scheduler_jobs; 

select * from user_jobs;
```

for jobs created with DBMS_SCHEDULER or DBMS_JOB, respectively.

---

Date format can be set in "Tools" - "Preference"s menu, under the "Database" node, NLS settings.

**[EDIT]**

If you want to specify format every time, you can do that in both `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` functions (depending on what you're doing). Here are a few examples:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') one_date,
  2         to_char(date '2019-08-25', 'mon, dd yyyy') two_date,
  3         to_date('12-18-2018 13:22', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi') three_date
  4  from dual;

ONE_DATE         TWO_DATE     THREE_DATE
---------------- ------------ -------------------
08.03.2019 13:15 kol, 25 2019 18.12.2018 13:22:00

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I appreciate that. For date format, i want to manually assign date format each time in my query and not in NLS settings. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found good results from this query, `select * from dba_scheduler_jobs;`